# How to make Enum literal case insensitive in Xtext

Tags: validation, grammar, case-insensitive, rule, xtext

I have defined an EnumRule like following in my Xtext grammar file:

`enum MySpec_directionEnum:
left='"left"' | right='"right"' | none='"none"';`

With this rule the allowed enum values are `"left", "right" and "none"` (all in lower case). I want to be able to allow these values in any case(case insensitive). For example I want to also allow the values to be `"left" or "Left" or "LEFT" or "LeFt"`  and so on.

But I just want values of *MySpec_directionEnum* enum to be case insensitive and not all enums in my grammar file. Is it possible through grammar or some kind of validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best option is to replace the enum rule with an ordinary parser rule, like

```
MySpec_directionEnum:
    value=STRING;
```

and check if `value` is a permitted string (case-insensitive variant of "left", "right" or "none") in the validator:

```
@Check
public void check(MySpec_directionEnum e) {
    String lowercaseValue = e.getValue().toLowerCase();
    if (!lowercaseValue.equals("left")) {
        error("Expected \"left\".", e, 
            ArithmeticsPackage.Literals.MY_SPEC_DIRECTION_ENUM__VALUE,
            validationMessageAcceptor.INSIGNIFICANT_INDEX);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It does solve my query. Could there be a better solution possible for this?

Comment: @Kuldeep Jain: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: This may not give completion suggestions however.

Answer (score 0):

if you are very hardworking to write up all possibilities you could try

```
enum TestEnum:
    x='x'| x='X' | y='y' | y='Y'
;
```

Comment: This gives a warning from XText.